# When I have to query Apple's Feedback Service

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

One thing I haven't found is **when** to call the Apple's Feedback Service for push notifications. The [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1) says:

> Providers **should periodically query** the feedback service to get the list of device tokens for their applications, each of which is identified by its topic. Then, after verifying that the application hasn’t recently been re-registered on the identified devices, a provider should stop sending notifications to these devices.

But is there a best practice to follow? E.g.:

1. Everyone calls it *before sending any notification*, or
2. Everyone calls it *once a day*, or
3. Everyone calls it *once a week*, or
4. ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the feedback service every day, or if you send lots of notifications in a day, every hour if it's not a problem for you.

The reason to call the feedback service is to reduce the number of subscribers to include in the next send.

The frequency of calling depends of the frequency of the sending of notifications.

Comment: In the [Technical Note TN2265](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html) we can read "You should check the feedback service at least once a day for device tokens that are no longer active."